# An issue with React and flexbox

Tags: css, reactjs

Trying to create a calculator with React and flexbox, and its seems my flexbox is not working.

I tried using the chrome dev tools and its the same thing

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './App.css';
import Button from "./components/Button";

class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
<div className="App">
  <div className="calc-wrapper">
    <div className="rows">
      <Button>7</Button>`
      <Button>8</Button>
      <Button>9</Button>
      <Button>/</Button>
    </div>
    <div className="rows">
      <Button>7</Button>
      <Button>8</Button>
      <Button>9</Button>
      <Button>/</Button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

`this` is the css file enter code here

```
.App{
display: flex;` 
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
}

.calc-wrapper{
 width: 400px;
 height: 600px;
 }

.rows{
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 }
```

Instead of the number centered in a box-like visualizing the calculator button, its just on its own, stacked together

Comment: Is style is applying to the elements? If not then check the css path using dev tool.

Comment: Also, if your style isn't applying, it looks like you have a rogue character after `display:flex;` which could be causing compilation issue.

Comment: How do you want them to look?

Comment: Ok, i am following up on a tutorial on how react can be used to create a claculator. Right now, I am suppose to bet the look of a calculator button with each number in its own box and not just 789/, Just a mac calculator type. The numbers are already placed at the middle as i want it to be but still not placed in individual box to form individual button

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `calc-wrapper`'s display property to `flex`, and `flex-direction` property to `column`. Because `row`s live inside `calc-wrapper`, not `App`.

Check out working examle on: 
https://jsfiddle.net/mn0r3gxu/3/